# Firefox Becomes Unstable Playing Youtube Videos

Tags: firefox, youtube

I'm having an issue with Firefox.  Anytime I try to play a video on YouTube (or an embedded YouTube video on another site) my browser becomes unstable.  The video is jumpy, going full screen to window takes a while and changing/closing the tab or pausing the video can sometimes take over a minute.  This seems to be a recent issue with Firefox 35.  Chrome works fine, although I much prefer Firefox as a browser.  This happens both when I'm using HTML5 or Flash (libflash version is 11.2.202.275) as the viewer on YouTube.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit with version 331.113 of the proprietary nVidia drivers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this by disabling all of my extensions and then adding them back in one by one.  For some reason Firebug or the Web Developer extension seemed to be causing the issue.  I disabled both of those and now things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube use HTML5 now, so the control (play, stop, volume) is in ECMAscript. You can set "dom.max_script_run_time" to the value 20 in "about:config". Look how you can do this right at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/warning-unresponsive-script